# Github site admin curl not working for active users

Tags: github, curl

```
curl -L -u DEV:$DEVTOKEN https://github.company-name.net/api/v3/stafftools/reports/active_users.csv

{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/3.6/rest"
}
```

I am trying to curl by following directions here
https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/admin/configuration/configuring-your-enterprise/site-admin-dashboard

Why am I getting not found message error?

Answer (score 0):

The ["Reports" instruction](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/admin/configuration/configuring-your-enterprise/site-admin-dashboard#reports) does not include `api/v3`:

> The site admin dashboard offers a Reports section as an alternative, making it easy for you to download CSV reports with most of the information that you are likely to need for users, organizations, and repositories.
>
> ```
> curl -L -u USERNAME:TOKEN http(s)://HOSTNAME/stafftools/reports/all_users.csv
> ```